# Material Raised Button with Default Background

Tags: android, button

I am trying to create a button whose text color is the `colorAccent` and whose background color is the default background color.

It looks like this:
[image]

I have tried default styles, but non of them have worked. Currently I have something like this but doesn't work:

`styles.xml` :

```
<style name="AppTheme.ButtonRaised" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

And layout:

```
          <Button
                app:theme="@style/AppTheme.ButtonRaised"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="date" />
```

And I am getting something like this:

[image]

I am not getting any effect of style or theme here. I have also tried with `style` tag, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

apply theme with a style like this

```
    <style name="ThemeButtonBlue" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: not sure but I think your "AppTheme"'s parent and button's parent "Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored" are not same that's causing the problem

Comment: Nope.. It didn't work! Background color gone. But pressed state shadows are wired. Text is also not capitalized.

Comment: to capitalize text use "android:textAllCaps="true"" in your xml's <Button > tag. change color accent to change the pressed state color

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123757/discussion-between-nilabja-and-kirtan403).

Answer (score 0):

I am also struggling to do this effect. I could achieve something similar, but I don't know if its "material design approved".
I set the style to their button borderless colored and the elevation to 2dp because on material design they say that "Raised buttons have a default elevation of 2dp". But they don't give you xml layout examples which is annoying -_-

```
   <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:text="Button"/>
```

Keep in mind that the elevation tag does not show a shadow pre Lollipop devices.